# I'm told python threading doesn't mean my code runs in parallel, but it sort of does. can someone explain?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I got the following code and when I run it, the first function returns Done after 5 seconds and the second one after 10 seconds, not 15. This, logically speaking, means they both run at the same time, yet everyone says threading is not parallel running. Can someone shed some light on what's happening on the background, please?

```
import threading
import time

def dummy(param):
    time.sleep(param)
    print('done')

param1 = 10
param2 = 5

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=dummy, args=(param1,))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=dummy, args=(param2,))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Comment: Who's `everyone`, threading works in paralle as long as you can use more than 1 CPU core

Comment: you might want to read about the [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/)

Comment: Short version: Two threads can _wait_ for different things (e.g., wait for input from different network clients) at the same time, but in Python in particular, because of the _GIL_ that @ilias-sp told you about, you can't use threads for [_parallel computing_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a good test. [Sleeping gives up the CPU as far as I know](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328586/how-does-sleeping-a-thread-work), so the first `sleep` releases the CPU to the second thread and then that one starts `sleep`ing. You aren't doing work on multiple threads at once. Both threads are sleeping, not running and doing work.

People say that you can't use multithreading to run code in parallel because in CPython, the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) prevents multiple bytecode instructions from running simultaneously in different threads in the same process. That means that two threads can't do work at *precisely* the same time.

You *can* however have I/O tasks running in parallel, since, for example,  waiting for a socket to return data doesn't require heavy work on the CPU. I believe for the purposes of the explanation here, sleeping the thread can be thought of as closer to waiting on long-running I/O than having the CPU do work. That means that yes, the two sleeps can happen in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Carcigenicate gave a good answer, much of 'what is happening in the background' asked about in the question. I try to open it a bit too.

Threads are started in the background of your main execution. No matter whether there are multiple cores or not, or whether the GIL is active or not.

Your thread.start() calls return immediately and are ran right one after the other, practically at the same time in your example. So after 10 seconds both are done. Threads always work like that.

If there is only one core, the operating system gives each thread some time almost all the time, like every millisecond maybe. If you use Python with GIL (the default official from python.org, called CPython), multiple cores are not used at the exact same time for Python code that sets the lock. It is possible to release the lock in C code for Python, and AFAIK e.g. libraries for reading from disk or network do that. For your Python code, maybe it runs one line from one thread, then the other, but it's still practically simultaneous on your gigahertz range processor.

Now, if you want to test performance benefit of running multiple threads, for example a worker thread per core, that you must test with a test function that does some work. Even just counts numbers. Then if you run many in parallel, vs sequentially, you'll see differences depending on number of cores and whether GIL is there or not. I thought PyPy doesn't have GIL but apparently it does, https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-pypy-have-a-gil-why . IronPython and Jython do not, I'd test IronPython for a non-GIL Python, https://ironpython.net/